# How to allow configurable product on Grouped product?

Tags: magento-community, grouped-products

I am trying to add grouped product(s) with configurable product(s) and using the AITOC extensions "Custom Options for Grouped Product", however it only allows simple product(s) with or without custom options only but not a configurable product(s) that I need. I already modified app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml, and added `<configurable/>` under

```
<config>
    <global>
        <catalog>
            <product>
                <type>
                    <grouped>
                        <allow_product_types>
```

so that it will allow configurable product(s).But, when I checked on the product view page, the configurable product I added on that grouped product was showing though but not its option(s).

I hope anyone can help me to solve this. A big Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There is a reason the `<allow_product_types>` does not contain the `<configurable />` product type. Magento does not have support for configurable products inside the grouped products. If you modified this, any configurable product listed in the grouped product will be treated as a simple product.
Honestly I share your interest in this, it would be a nice feature to have but it involves a lot of coding.
I haven't seen any extensions that allow this. Maybe the code 'amount' is the reason no one does this.
Maybe a good work around would be to include in the grouped product all the simple products that compose the configurable products (you may need to change the visibility of these products but I'm not sure.) Then the customer can choose what he/she needs.
Here is an example. Let's say you have 2 configurable products:

1. A couch that can be sold in black or white. (so color is the configurable attribute).
2. A coffee table sold in yellow and blue (again color is the configurable attribute)

Then you make the grouped product called `Minimalist Living room` that should contain your 2 configurable products, but instead it will contain 4 simple products:

1. White Couch
2. Black Couch
3. Yellow coffee table
4. Blue coffee table

Then the customer can choose a couch and a coffee table (or more) and you get the desired result.

---

<sub>I know that noone in their right mind will buy a combination like that (or would they?) but I think you get the point of what I'm saying.</sub>

Comment: Hi! Yes, I tried to allow it on grouped products but as you've said it treated the configurable product as simple which can give an error. I already purchased an extension for this but the features are limited and still trying to learn how I can make this works. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the suggestion, Marius.  I'm thinking about just creating a custom option (Coffee Table), and then adding in some custom logic that adds that additional simple product to the cart if they have that custom option selected.  In my case I have a configurable product and want an additional Simple product to be grouped in.  Does that sound crazy?

Comment: I just ran into this problem. What if you're selling a bed set that is a grouped listing? Bed + nightstand + dresser + mirror. But the bed is available in 2 different sizes: Queen or Eastern King. So the product listing is originally configurable, and the grouped products are complimenting the product listing. Someone recommended have configurable listing + have these bed set pieces as "upsell" products assigned to it, but it is checkboxes instead of qty input fields, not offering very friendly user interaction. If anyone can help with extension this let me know!

Answer (score 0):

This post talks about how to go about doing it. It's not complete, but it's the best that I've found. 
http://www.brimllc.com/2010/12/magento-grouped-products-containing-associated-configurable-products/

The same company has packaged their work into a module.  The module has been kept more current than the blog post, and it works, best I can tell.
http://ecommerce.brimllc.com/grouped-options.html